# Routes translation with Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to add translations for the defined routes in an existing Symfony 3 web application. I see that Symfony 4 already has this functionality implemented* and you can just:

```yaml
foo:
  path:
    en: contact
    es: contacto
    cat: contacte
```

*(From https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing)*

however with Symfony 3 it seems that you have to configure different route names for each locale. I would need to keep the route names the same if possible, because a lot of logic depends on the route name.

I tried with [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) but it seems that it's not keeping the same route names.

Any idea to get the same route name for different locales and have them translated?

Comment: You mean like with the locale parameter ({_locale})? You can use the same route name but do end up with different paths. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html#advanced-routing-example

Comment: @Jeroen but how can you translate the routes like in the example above with this approach?

Comment: Is there any good reason to stick to Symfony 3 and not simply update to Symfony 4?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, PHP 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer from [this JMSI18nRoutingBundle issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/issues/218#issuecomment-352632961). It's not documented so someone has to just figure it out:

You need to create a `routes.<locale>.yml` for each locale in translations directory with route_name and locale_route as key value. E.g.

```yaml
# routes.en.yml
contact: /contact
who_we_are: /who-we-are
```

```yaml
# routes.es.yml
contact: /contacto
who_we_are: /quienes-somos
```

and so on.

Then you just need to clear the cache to get those routes working.

You can also use the default route definition for your default locale and avoid one of those files.